# Clustered annotation pins take more time to add them on Mapview

Tags: mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I'm trying to add multiple annotations(nearly 30k) to map view, for this I use clustering mechanism and I added those group pins to map view, my problem is the pins take more time to add on map view and the map is not moving smoothly after those clustered pins are added, how to reduce that time and how to make the map move smoothly. Please show me the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An pin is a pin. Whether it represents 1,000 points or 1 it is still one annotation and won't go any slower. Maybe show us your viewForAnnotation class and we'll see if you're doing some calculation there that slows the drawing down.